# Blender 2.8 render border not showing solid objects outside of border

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-border

I have this render border set in one of my scenes:
[image]
However, when I go into rendered view, everything outside the render border stops being displayed:
[image]
Any ideas on what could be causing this?
Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the point of the render border.

Comment: You should still be able to view what's outside the render border: http://prntscr.com/ndbnjc - I took this screenshot in 2.79b, but 2.8 seems to behave differently. Is that intended?

Comment: Yep, this is intended. Restricting the the render area is for the purpose of speeding up render time while still be able to see modifications to the material. The rest of the model gets still rendered, but with a clay material and without any lighting instead of GLSL output in Blender 2.79.